# Pandas Inserted column in CSV gets round down

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to insert a new column and write my calculations in this column, but Pandas keeps rounding down the values of the newly inserted column

```
fileName = 'File.dat'
colnames=['junk', 'X', 'Y', 'P'] 

pd.options.display.precision = 10

df = pd.read_csv(fileName, sep = ' ', names=colnames, header=None)
df.drop(df.columns[0],axis = 1, inplace = True)
df.insert(3,'S',0)

df['S'][0] = 2.731
```

and the result I get:

```
                X             Y             P  S
0   -0.6109808683 -0.6784414649   1.212175369  2
1   -0.6717514396 -0.6717514396   2.204230785  0
2   -0.6717514396 -0.6717514396   2.204230785  0
```

Why the values in 'S' column gets round down?
How can I stop this behavior?

Comment: you chained your indexers. You want `df.loc[0, 'S'] = 2.761`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either change the datatype of the column as float , or while inserting the default value for columns 'S' change 0 to 0.0

```
fileName = 'File.dat'
colnames=['junk', 'X', 'Y', 'P'] 

pd.options.display.precision = 10

df = pd.read_csv(fileName, sep = ' ', names=colnames, header=None)
df.drop(df.columns[0],axis = 1, inplace = True)
df.insert(3,'S',0.0)

df.loc[0,'S']= 2.731
```

Comment: Don't chain indexers. Use `df.loc[0, 'S'] = 2.731`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it thinks that the type is an integer. There are a number of ways to address it, such as specifying the type at load. Alternatively, you can simply write

```
df = pd.read_csv(fileName, sep = ' ', names=colnames, header=None)
df["S"] = df["S"].astype(float)
```

Comment: I recommend not assigning columns with the dot-accessors. In general it's easy to overwrite a DataFrame method and get unexpected results further down the road. Instead do either `df['S'] = df['S'].astype(float)` or `df = df.assign(S=df['S'].astype(float))`

Comment: @PaulH I see your point, and it makes sense. On the other hand, the tab completion works for dot notation excellently in Jupyter for dot, not for strings (admittedly not an issue for something called "S"). It's a tradeoff, I think.

Comment: FWIW, jupyer can now tab-complete dataframe names through traditional accessors. Also, one can easily imagine a column named "T". Which *could* wreak havoc. Dot-accessors are fine if you know what you're doing. But I don't think we should be encouraging them on SO

Comment: To boot, jupyter's dataframe-specific string tab completion is *better* if you have special characters or spaces in your column names.

Comment: @PaulH Good to know, thanks! I guess it's not in the version used at my workplace. Anyway, corrected.